# What is the syntax to instantiate a structured dtype in numpy?

Tags: numpy, genome, structured-array

If I have a dtype like

```
foo = dtype([('chrom1', '<f4', (100,)), ('chrom2', '<f4', (13,))])
```

How can I create an instance of that dtype, as a scalar.

Background, in case There's A Better Way:

I want to efficiently represent arrays of scalars mapping directly to the bases in a genome, chromosome by chromosome.  I don't want arrays of these genomic arrays, each one is simply a structured set of scalars that I want to reference by name/position, and be able to add/subtract/etc.

It appears that dtype.type() is maybe the path forward, but I haven't found useful documentation for correctly calling this function yet.

So suppose I have:

```
chrom1_array = numpy.arange(100)
chrom2_array = numpy.arange(13)
genomic_array = foo.type([chrom1_array, chrom2_array])
```

That last line isn't right, but hopefully it conveys what I'm currently attempting.

Is this a horrible idea?  If so, what's the right idea?  If not, what's the correct way to implement it?

This sort of works, but is terrible:

```
 bar = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('chrom1', 'f4', 100), ('chrom2', 'f4', 13)])[0]
```

Comment: I think the closest you can get to that is a "scalar array": `bar = np.array((chrom1_array, chrom2_array), dtype=foo)`.  `bar` is an array with shape `()`.

Comment: How many of these 'genomic_array's are there?  What kinds of math operations are you doing with them?  So far your description does not make a good case for using structured arrays.  Multidimensional arrays are your best choice for efficient math, and class/objects best for defining complex objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
foo = np.dtype([('chrom1', '<f4', (100,)), ('chrom2', '<f4', (13,))])
t = np.zeros((), dtype=foo)
```

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realize you could pass the empty tuple as a shape.  Cool, thanks.

Comment: You can then fill values with `t['chrom1']=chrom1_array`.  Or you can create and fill in one step: `t1=np.array((chrom1_array, chrom2_array),dtype=foo)`.

Comment: But how useful is this 'scalar' array?  Any more or less useful than `d={'chrom1':chrom1_array, 'chrom2':chrom2_array}`?